# Will Entity Framework 5 run under .NET 5?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

Will Entity Framework 5 run under .NET 5? I ask this because I tried to upgrade my app to EF 6 and was unsuccessful. So sticking with EF 5. Does this mean I can't go to .NET 5?

Comment: I know MS has done some work on EF 6.4 for it to be able to run on .NET Core and thus most likely also .NET 5 - but I **highly** doubt that they'll backport all that extra effort to an older version of EF. It you want to go .NET 5, you'll have to start using EF Core 5.

Comment: No. What made upgrading unsuccessful?

Comment: I finally succeeded. The problem was I still had a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll which contains the EF 5 EntityConnection. NuGet did not remove this so I got no compile errors using the wrong class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, given that EF 5 only runs under full .NET Framework, I will not run under .NET 5. You must either upgrade to EF 6.3 or later, or switch to EF Core 5.